# C# WPF ListBox - losing and getting focus when changing selection

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, selectionchanged, lostfocus

I have a problem which I really can't solve at all.

When my listbox is focus and I change my selection, then the "selection changed" function gets called, I am ok with that. But the "lostfocus" and "gotfocus" functions get called too. How can I prevent that? When I change my selection I only want the "selection changed" function to be called.

xaml:

```
<ListBox ... GotFocus="lbMemberships_GotFocus" LostFocus="lbMemberships_LostFocus" SelectionChanged="lbMemberships_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Comment: Both LostFocus and GotFocus are routed events which means that a child element of the ListBox, such as an individual ListBoxItem or any of its child elements, may fire these events and your event handler will still get invoked. Why are you handling these events in the first place? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @mm8 does the sender of the event change if the event was fired by a child element?

Comment: No, but you could check the OriginalSource property of the EventArgs.